# Bind list of strings in yml (one level ) to Java list in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I have a yml file with the following list of strings:

```
list-of-strings:
 - el1
 - el2
 - el3
```

I have implemented a config class to retrieve it:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "list-of-strings")
public class ListOfStringsConfig {

    private List<String> listOfStrings;

    public List<String> getListOfStrings) {
        return listOfStrings;
    }
}
```

which is not able to retrieve the list of strings (when I access listOfStrings it raises NullPointerException).
I've noticed that if I change the yml by putting 2 levels like:

```
list:
  strings:
   - el1
   - el2
   - el3
```

and modify the config accordingly:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "list")
public class ListOfStringsConfig {

    private List<String> strings;

    public List<String> getStrings) {
        return strings;
    }
}
```

it works as expected.
Since for my case having 2 levels has no meaning at all, I was wondering if there is a way to make it work with the first use case, so only one level in the yaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need just one level, then you need to remove the prefix. The way it works is prefix + variable name to map the values.

That being said, I would not recommend it as it would be much easier to have something that already exists.

Side note: if you only have one value to fetch, you could use `@Value` instead

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. You are required to have prefix setting. This could be a little cleaner, even though it's still two levels:

```
list.strings:
   - el1
   - el2
   - el3
```